# How to add scribe client for nodejs app with winston logs

Tags: node.js, logging, winston, facebook-scribe

I have been using winston for logging in my node application.Now I need to setup scribe for aggregating the application logs.I noticed the node-scribe client for node app to interact with scribe client.But my doubt is how to make the existing logs to interact with the scribe client without changing my logging from winston.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There's a [winston-scribe](https://npmjs.org/package/winston-scribe) npm module. Its source code has been removed from github but it's still there in npm registry. It's fairly simple (49 lies of code) and depends on [scribe](https://npmjs.org/package/scribe) module (hosted on github as [node-scribe](https://github.com/Applifier/node-scribe)). Just install it, import the `Scribe` transport and give it a try.

DISCLAIMER: I haven't tested it but I think it should work.